# Get all signed/logged in AD B2C users from Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

Is there a Graph API to get all Signed in AD B2C users(Guests/Members). Couldn't find this information in the Graph API docs. Have checked the below links.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations

Answer (score 1):

With REST APIs, the concept of "Signed In" isn't really applicable. This is because OAuth and REST are stateless. OAuth Access Tokens expire in a relatively short time (typically 1 hour) and while there is also a Refresh Token, it could be days or months before it is exchanged for a new Access Token.

Comment: Ok so that means if I have to check the Sign In activity of a User I have to rely on the activity Logs/sign in logs ? And filter the logs for recent sign ins (typically 1 hour window).

Comment: That only tells you when the token was retrieved. Also keep in mind that a single User might have dozens of tokens issued at the same time. Every individual application that they're consented to gets it's own token and could be refreshed at any time without user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

The service is stateless. You cannot determine who is logged in at any given moment, only who logged in in the last X hours through the Sign In logs.